# NameError: name 'word' is not defined in hangman game

Tags: python, function, request

I am trying to create a hangman game.

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/<user>/Downloads/wordgame.py", line 23, in <module>
so_far= "-" * len(word)
NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

If anyone could please help me out on how to fix this and if you could please look over my code and give me some tips if I am heading in the right direction and anyway to improve. Thank you.

```
import random
HANGMAN = ('''
 O''', '''

 O    
 |''', '''

 O    
/|\ ''', '''

 O    
/|\ 
  \ ''', '''

 O    
/|\ 
/ \ ''')

words=['train','tees','tweed','conquer','conquet','washing']
lives = len(HANGMAN) - 1
wrong = 0
used = []
so_far= "-" * len(word)

print ("Welcome to Hangman!")

def pickaword():
    word = random.choice(words)
    return word

def displayBoard(HANGMAN, wrongLetters, correctLetters, word):
    print (HANGMAN[len(missedLetters)])
    print ("wrong letters:")
    for letter in wrongLetters:
        print (letter, end )

def guessaletter(guessedLetters):
    while True:
        guess = raw_input("Guess a letter.")
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print("Please only enter a single letter.")
        # Stops user from inputing more that 1 letter.
        elif guess in guessedLetters:
            print("You have already guessed that letter. Choose again!")
        # Stops user from guessing the same letter twice.
        elif guess not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz":
            print("Please enter a valid letter")
        # Stops user from enterting a invalid letter
        else:
            return guess

def guessaword(word, wrong, so_farm, lives):
    while wrong < lives and so_far != word:
        print (HANGMAN[wrong])
        print ("You have used the following letters:" + used)
        print ("So farm the word is", + so_far)



"""def reveal(hidden, guessedLetters):
    display = ''
    for letter in hidden:
        letter += display        
    else:
        lives -=1

    return display"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use global

```
def pickaword():
    global word
    word = random.choice(words)
```

and then use the global variable outside the function or indside another function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to get the length of a variable `word` which does not exist.

You need to use your `pickaword` function first, to give `word` a value:

```
word = pickaword()
```

A good next step, which could also help understand this problem, would be to start making the function or loop in which the user plays the game. One of the first things that you'll have to do is choose a word for the user to guess. Only once you've chosen a word can you display `so_far`. But if a word hasn't been chosen then it's not clear how many dashes you need.

Also you have a typo in `guessaword`: the third argument is probably supposed to be `so_far`.